# How are tags organized in HTML Table in DJango?

Tags: django, django-templates

[image: Table is inverted]

I am trying to orgainize an HTML table, however my intended rows are coming out in the same columns. Is their an additonal tag I should use to fix this?

Here is my html code and django template tags..

```
<table>
  <thead> 
    <th>height</th>
    <th>birthday</th>
  </thead>                
  <tr>
    {% for ht in height  %}
      <td>{{ ht.heightft }}' {{ ht.remainingInches }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    {% for b in bday  %}
      <td>{{ b.bday }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

view.py

```
def displayVitals(request):
height = Height.objects.all()
bday = UserBDay.objects.all()

my_dict={'height':height, 'bday':bday}

return render(request, 'profiles_api/user_vitals.html', context=my_dict)
```

models.py

```
class Height(models.Model):
userID = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
heightft = models.IntegerField()
remainingInches = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.userID)
```

Comment: How are `height` and `bday` generated? Usually you would generate and loop over an iterable where every element contained all data for a row

Comment: height and bday are two classes in my models.py.

Comment: Add your models and your view

Comment: Added my code for views and models. @IainShelvington

Comment: You've not added the `UserBDay` model but I assume it also has a foreign key to `UserProfile`? You should probably use a `UserProfile` queryset to generate your table rows. It's not clear why you were wanting to group your rows the way you were in the first place since you have not grouped them in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have more than two data, your data overflows the chart because it's in the wrong direction. Shouldn't it be:

```
| Height | Birthday |
|  5'6"  | 3/4/1999 |
|  6'4"  | 8/7/1996 |
        ...
```

If that's the case

```py
def displayVitals(request):
    height = Height.objects.all()
    bday = UserBDay.objects.all()
    my_dict = {'data': zip(height, bday)}  # pairs data up
    return render(request, 'profiles_api/user_vitals.html', context=my_dict)
```

```html
<table>
  <thead> 
    <th>height</th>
    <th>birthday</th>
  </thead>
  {% for height, bday in data %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ d.height }}</td>
      <td>{{ d.bday }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

You might want to re-check the variable names though.

Comment: Thanks @crimsonpython24 this solution worked. Thanks for showing me the Zip function.